# Natively extract ISO from CD with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, iso-image

Windows 7 has built-in support for burning an ISO to CD or DVD.  I'd like to go the other way, and have been looking around docs and Google, but can't find anything directly answering this:  Does Windows 7 have a native utility to make an ISO from a CD, or is an add-on such as ImgBurn or LC ISO Creator needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think a tool is included with this functionality. ImgBurn as you mentioned should work fine though.

Answer (score 4):

Windows 7 is unable to do this without third party software. As you stated, ImgBurn, UltraISO, MagicISO are all possible candidates.

Answer (score -1):

WinRAR - http://www.rarlab.com/ works great as well.  Just right click on the ISO file and select Extract.

Comment: Op asked:Does Windows 7 have a native utility to make an ISO from a CD?

Your answer is not answer to this question, so -1.