# Lite tools to copy CD to ISO

Tags: windows-xp, software-rec, iso-image, compact-disc

Lite tools to copy CD to ISO

Is there any freeware lite tools that can copy Cd to ISO?

OS is Windows XP SP3.

Comment: what operating system do you need it for?  note this has probably been asked & answered before...

Comment: here's one [for windows](http://superuser.com/questions/17260/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-an-iso-file-out-of-a-dvd) ... another [for windows](http://superuser.com/questions/73731/extract-iso-from-cd) ... one [for OSX](http://superuser.com/questions/85987/mac-os-x-best-way-to-make-an-iso) ... someone else find one for Linux...

Comment: Linux uses `dd`.

Comment: Closed and re-opened it, at least this one properly answers the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ImgBurn](http://fileforum.betanews.com/detail/ImgBurn/1128426215/1)

> ImgBurn is a lightweight CD / DVD / HD
>   DVD / Blu-ray burning application that
>   everyone should have in their toolkit!
>
> It has several 'Modes', each one for
>   performing a different task:
>
> Read - Read a disc to an image file
>   Build - Create an image file from
>   files on your computer or network - or
>   you can write the files directly to a
>   disc Write - Write an image file to a
>   disc Verify - Check a disc is 100%
>   readable. Optionally, you can also
>   have ImgBurn compare it against a
>   given image file to ensure the actual
>   data is correct Discovery - Put your
>   drive / media to the test! Used in
>   combination with DVDInfoPro, you can
>   check the quality of the burns your
>   drive is producing     ImgBurn supports
>   a wide range of image file formats -
>   including BIN, CUE, DI, DVD, GI, IMG,
>   ISO, MDS, NRG and PDI.
>
> It can burn Audio CD's from any file
>   type supported via DirectShow / ACM -
>   including AAC, APE, FLAC, M4A, MP3,
>   MP4, MPC, OGG, PCM, WAV, WMA and WV.
>
> You can use it to build DVD Video
>   discs (from a VIDEO_TS folder), HD DVD
>   Video discs (from a HVDVD_TS folder)
>   and Blu-ray Video discs (from a BDAV /
>   BDMV folder) with ease.
>
> It supports Unicode folder/file names,
>   so you shouldn't run in to any
>   problems if you're using an
>   international character set.
>
> ImgBurn supports all the Microsoft
>   Windows OS's - Windows 95, Windows 98,
>   Windows Me, Windows NT4, Windows 2000,
>   Windows XP, Windows 2003, Windows
>   Vista, Windows 2008 and Windows 7
>   (including all the 64-bit versions).
>   If you use Wine, it should also run on
>   Linux and other x86-based Unixes.
>
> It's a very flexible application with
>   several advanced features that are
>   often lacking in other tools,
>   especially when it comes to burning
>   DVD Video discs. It supports all the
>   latest drives without the need for
>   updates (including booktype /
>   bitsetting / advanced settings on many
>   of the major ones - i.e. BenQ, LiteOn,
>   LG, NEC, Plextor, Samsung, Sony).
>
> There is an image queue system for
>   when you're burning several images
>   (which you can automatically share
>   between multiple drives if you have
>   more than one) and an easy-to-use
>   layer break selection screen for
>   double layer DVD Video jobs. The
>   Automatic Write Speed feature allows
>   you store your favourite burn speed
>   settings on a per 'Media ID' basis,
>   right down to a drive by drive level.
>   Data captured during the burn (write
>   speed, buffer levels etc) can be
>   displayed / analysed using DVDInfoPro.
>
> Whilst ImgBurn is designed to work
>   perfectly straight out of the box,
>   advanced users will appreciate just
>   how configurable it is.
>
> Oh and let's not forget the best thing
>   about it.... it's 100% FREE ;-)
>
> Please do not use this software to
>   make illegal copies of copyrighted
>   discs.

Comment: +1 for ImgBurn, I've been using it for a while now and never looked back.

Comment: Great stuff - also allows creation of an ISO from a bunch of files, just what I need for VMs.

Comment: ImgBurn seems to have now turned into something that tries to install addware into your browser, without option to skip that.

Answer (score 1):

This really should get closed as a [duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/17260/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-an-iso-file-out-of-a-dvd), but I've used [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) and have been happy with it.